# heterogeneous database link from Oracle 12c to SQLServer 2012

Tags: sql-server, oracle, odbc

My problem: I want to link a Oracle 12c Enterprise with SQLServer 2012. I tried different tutorials but I didn't succeed. On my latest approach with heterogeneous services i got the following error when i try to query something:

select * from conf@PAS;

ORA-28545: Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535

conf is a table from the SQL Server and PAS is the name of my database link.

The different guides I followed said that I have to change 3 files to make the connection. I will post them below:

Note: Both of my databases are running on the same machine.

**listener.ora:**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\OracleDB\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\OracleDB\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC =
        (SID_NAME=PAS) 
        (ORACLE_HOME = C:\OracleDB\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1) 
        (PROGRAM = dg4odbc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = PASSRV1)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

**tnsnames.ora:**

```
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = PASSRV1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

PAS =
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1433))
      (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=PAS))
      (HS=OK)
    )
```

**initPAS.ora:**

```
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = PAS
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = OFF
```

I created the link with this command:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK PAS CONNECT TO "user" IDENTIFIED BY "password" USING 'PAS';
```

The thing is that i don't really know the cause of the error and I don't know how to resolve it. So I hope one of you can help me.

If there is a easier way to create the link I would appreciate it if you tell me. I am open for suggestions.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the oracle gateway and following a simple tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a similar problem, try first to test `tnsping` to `PAS`

```
cmd> tnsping PAS
```

after it if you don't have any problem about try to change the port of `PAS 1433` is already used by `SQL Server` in default configuration. Try to start listener without any errors.

Take in account that oracle database gateway for SQL Server has additional cost, if you `install cd 5` from oracle installation you could have problems with oracle audit.